# Relationship between holomorphy and directional derivatives

Tags: complex-analysis

Given an entire function $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, I would like to prove that the directional derivatives
$$
D_\alpha f(z) := \lim_{r\to 0}{\frac{f(z+re^{i\alpha})-f(z)}{re^{i\alpha}}}
$$
satisfy that
$$
D(z) := \frac{\max_\alpha{|D_\alpha f(z)|}}{\min_\alpha{|D_\alpha f(z)|}} \equiv 1
$$
My approach to the problem is to prove that $|D_\alpha f(z)|$ is continuous, since then, by holomorphy of $f$, it should be constant. Accordingly, I have reached the following reasoning
$$
\lim_{\alpha \to \alpha_0}{|D_\alpha f(z)| - |D_{\alpha_0} f(z)|} = 0 \iff \lim_{\alpha \to \alpha_0}{\left | |D_\alpha f(z)| - |D_{\alpha_0} f(z)| \right |} = 0
$$
and
$$
\left | |D_\alpha f(z)| - |D_{\alpha_0} f(z)| \right | \leq |D_\alpha f(z) - D_{\alpha_0} f(z)| = \frac{|f(z+re^{i\alpha})-f(z+re^{i\alpha_0})|}{r} \
$$
which I personally am not sure if should approach 0 when $\alpha \to \alpha_0$.

In conclusion, I am asking if my reasoning is true or if it is a good line to follow in this exercise. Any answer or suggestion will be gratefully appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is complex differentiable at a point $z$ then
$$
D_\alpha f(z) = \lim_{r\to 0}{\frac{f(z+re^{i\alpha})-f(z)}{re^{i\alpha}}} = f'(z)
$$
for every $\alpha$, i.e. the directional derivative does not depend on the direction. In particular,
$$
D(z) = \frac{\max_\alpha{|D_\alpha f(z)|}}{\min_\alpha{|D_\alpha f(z)|}} \equiv 1$$